# How to select certain numbers in RegEx?

Tags: regex

So I am trying to build an app which needs a Instant Form Validation and for that I need to use a bit of RegEx. I just don't know hot to regex this. I have learned it in school but have already forgotten it.

So have I have to do is: I have this 21 digit long Code for example: 
249765876358312345655

But I only need the 6 digits from 13 to 19

```regex
^.{13}123456.{2}$
```

What I mean by this, is throwing the first 13 numbers and last two numbers away only giving me the 6 numbers I want.
Example:
249765876358312345655 -> 123456

I really don't know how to use RegEx in this case.

Comment: Maybe `^[0-9]{13}123456[0-9]{2}$` is what you are looking for. What do you mean by *I only need the 6 digits from 13 to 19*

Comment: Don't know in which language you are living there, but maybe do a string split/extract.  Seems more elegant to me.

Comment: This would be a good idea but in Javascript to use split on a random number seem a bit wrong to be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a [capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html):

```
^\d{13}(\d{6})\d{2}$
```

The digits you need are the ones of this group.

For example, in JavaScript:

```
let digits = "249765876358312345655".match(/^\d{13}(\d{6})\d{2}$/)[1]
```

returns

```
"123456"
```